# Android how to start Fragment like Activity launch Mode do

Tags: android, fragment

such as Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment D.

how can i restart Fragment A just like Activity singleTask launch mode.

The way I figure out that Fragment D invoke popBackStack 4 Time And add a New Fragment A to backstack. Using Fragment animation to make it look like back to FragmentA. But it's just a visiual cheating.

And someTime, I don't know how many times I have to popBackStack.

Is there any way to do that without using Jetpack Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the function can solve this question.

`popBackStack(String name, flag)`

I use it wrongly before which make it didn't work.  (what a stupid mistake, I forget to set Framgent name in backstack)

We need to set the fragment name while add to fragment backstack.
After we set the name, `popBackStack(name, flag)` can work.
while flag = 0, the target Fragment will not be popped;
while flag = 1, the target Fragment will be popped too;

```java
    public void addFragmentToBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                .replace(R.id.fl_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```